# javascript remove and re-add it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with the element `.remove`. 
I need a method to remove the the `id="tut"`and be able to re-use the `id="tut"` if if new data will be clicked.

Any suggestion? thank you for your help.

```
<span id="tut" style="font-weight:bold"></span>

<button id="delete">Remove</button>

$('#delete').on('click', function(){
    $('#tut').remove();  
});
```

Comment: Consider hiding and showing the element by setting the visibility or display CSS properties. Edit: ⬇️ use that ⬇️

Comment: I second this. Is there are a reason you are not using .hide() and .show()?

Comment: Do you need to remove the element itself or just the `id` attribute? If it's the latter, you can use `removeAttribute()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well why not using .empty() ?

```
<button id="delete">Remove</button>
$('#delete').on('click', function(){
    $('#tut').empty();  
});
```

If you need the whole `<span>` to be removed, you better generate it then!
Later you better select a wrapping container when the span becomes a non-Dom element.

**UPDATE** To enrich the answer and for those who expect from this question Title, a way resurrect an element after removing it.

There is another jQuery function called detach() capable of detaching (temporary removing) an element with it's content but that could be re-appended when needed !

```
<span id="tut" style="font-weight:bold">Immortal</span>

<button id="kill">Kill</button>
<button id="resurrect">Resurrect</button>

$('#kill').on('click', function(){
    zombie = $("#tut").detach();
});

$('#resurrect').on('click', function(){
    $("body").append(zombie);
});
```

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/gejsk7w2/

Comment: thank you!!!! it works. i did not know this function thank you so much!!!

Comment: I almost thought I misunderstood you! Because like others asking here your question means also removing the attribute (ID) which is another confusing story :) Glad It helped you

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked for me once I added the jQuery library (`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`).

There's a working example here: https://codepen.io/edlucas/pen/JjoMRpG

Not to be patronizing, but it's hard to tell from your example: if you're not separating your JavaScript in a new file, you must surround it with `<script></script>` tags.